# Can I get Process to not close the stdin pipe?

Tags: symfony, symfony-process

I encountered an edge case where I don't want `Process` to perform `fclose($this-pipes[0])` in `Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\AbstractPipes::write` (line 161 in my copy, using Symfony 6.3) - the `unset` that follows it is fine.

Currently I work around this problem like this:

```php
$p = new Process(...$args);
$p->setInput((function () {
    while (true) {
        yield "";
    }
})());
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

**The specific case**

`docker compose exec --no-TTY` and `docker exec -i` exit early, even though the underlying command is still running (and producing output) if stdin is closed. (clarification: `docker exec` without `-i` exits early as normal behaviour, so that's why I mentioned the version that does take the `-i` parameter)

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly better way:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Process\InputStream;

$p->setInput(new InputStream());
```

If I don't `->write()` anything to the stream object, its behaviour is identical to my generator in the question text.